# C# get list of only files that have "Date created" in last hour

Tags: c#, file, datetime

I am trying to get a list of only files that were created in last 60 minutes, My logic is returning all files

```
        static void check_file_date(string path)
        {
            foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                DateTime modification = File.GetCreationTime(s);
                if (modification < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(modification);
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                    Console.WriteLine("File created in last 60 minutes");
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine(modification);
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                    Console.WriteLine("File not created in last 60 minutes");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: BTW you should use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`, it will save you thousands of calls to `File.GetCreationTime()` -- the OS API already returns the creation time during enumeration, and `Directory.GetFiles()` throws away all the information except the name

Comment: Hi @Fenomatik, I have a little concern. The `modification` variable naming maybe confuse, it should be renamed as `creationTime` for better naming as you are getting the File's `CreationTime`.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
modification > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-60)
```

Comment: Probably even clearer... `(DateTime.Now - modification).TotalMinutes < 60`

Comment: Hi @Tarik, a little question from my side. Is it better to store the `DateTime.Now` into a variable before the loop and compare. As if do a comparison like this `modification > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-60)`, the `DateTime.Now` will keep updating (as in loop) and concern that the output result maybe inaccurate.

Comment: @YongShun I would pick up all the file names first, then filter against the current date once. It's more consistent. That's said, if for example it's about performing I/O on the files, by the time we process the first file, time has already changed and some files might already have become older than 60 minutes. I would still go for the one time approach though.

Comment: @BenVoigt Agree. It makes the intent much clearer.